# Mysql wrong index after InnoDB compression

Tags: mysql, indexing, compression, innodb

I have 2 mysql servers (master and slave). I've enabled InnoDB compression on Slave, after that mysql sometimes chooses wrong index on query.

Explain on Master:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                         | rows      | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+-----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | range  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL                        | 112017572 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | l     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       |            p.loan_ID        |         1 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | af    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       |            p.fromAccount_ID |         1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | at    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       |            p.toAccount_ID   |         1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Explain on Slave:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                                                 | key                | key_len | ref                         | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | l     | index  | PRIMARY                                                                       | FK243910AAD869E6   | 9       | NULL                        | 804876 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | ref    | PRIMARY,FK4BE7532292C5D482,FK4BE75322AE503A13,FK4BE75322382D11BC,POSTING_DATE | FK4BE75322382D11BC | 9       |            l.ID             |    101 | Using index condition; Using where           |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | af    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                       | PRIMARY            | 8       |            p.fromAccount_ID |      1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | at    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                       | PRIMARY            | 8       |            p.toAccount_ID   |      1 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

```
SELECT 
      p.ID AS 'payment_id',
      p.loan_ID AS 'loan_id',
      l.client_ID AS 'client_ID',
      p.amount AS 'amount',
      p.postingDate AS 'payment_date',
             CASE 
                 WHEN af.acc_type = 'POLCH' THEN 'wallet'    
                 WHEN af.acc_type = 'PLTCH' THEN 'wallet'        
                 WHEN af.acc_type = 'CNTT' THEN 'bank'        
                 WHEN af.acc_type = 'CNT2' THEN 'bank'        
                 WHEN af.acc_type = 'KONCH' THEN 'bank'        
                 WHEN af.acc_type = 'KRDTM' THEN 'cash'        
                 WHEN af.acc_type = 'LDRCH' THEN 'bank'        
                 ELSE concat('UNKNOWN_',af.acc_type) 
                 END AS 'payment_system_type', 
      af.description AS 'payment_system' 
      FROM Posting AS p 
      INNER JOIN Account AS af ON p.fromAccount_ID = af.ID 
      INNER JOIN Account AS at ON p.toAccount_ID = at.ID 
      INNER JOIN Loan AS l ON p.loan_id = l.ID 
      WHERE ( 
             af.acc_type = 'KONCH' 
             OR af.acc_type = 'PLTCH' 
             OR af.acc_type = 'POLCH' 
             OR af.acc_type = 'KRDTM' 
             OR  af.acc_type = 'LDRCH' 
             OR af.acc_type = 'CNT2' 
             OR af.acc_type = 'CNTT') 
             AND at.acc_type = 'ABON' 
             AND p.postingDate < DATE(now()) 
             AND p.ID > 0 
ORDER BY p.ID LIMIT 10000;
```

Loan - l

Posting - P

Master:

```
| Loan  | CREATE TABLE `Loan` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amount` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amountToReturn` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isGivenOut` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `isPaid` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `issueDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `loanPeriod` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `productType` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `realPayDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `givenOutDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `isPaidByBank` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `accountNumberNBKI` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `needManualProcessing` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isReverted` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `showInNBCHReport` bit(1) DEFAULT b'1',
  `stake` decimal(19,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ignoreProlongation` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `stakeAfter21` decimal(19,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `showInEquifaxReport` bit(1) DEFAULT b'1',
  `ignoreNbch` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FK2439106EC0BA18` (`product_ID`),
  KEY `ISPAID_INDEX` (`isPaid`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `ISP_ISGOUT_INDEX` (`isPaid`,`isGivenOut`),
  KEY `ISSUEDATE_INDEX` (`issueDate`),
  KEY `FK243910735827C6` (`discount_id`),
  KEY `idx_Loan_realPayDate` (`realPayDate`),
  KEY `idx_Loan_givenOutDate` (`givenOutDate`),
  KEY `FK243910AAD869E6` (`client_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `_FK243910735827C6` FOREIGN KEY (`discount_id`) REFERENCES `Discount` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2000623399 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 

 Posting | CREATE TABLE `Posting` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amount` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postingDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `fromAccount_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `loan_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `toAccount_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sourceType` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FK4BE7532292C5D482` (`fromAccount_ID`),
  KEY `FK4BE75322AE503A13` (`toAccount_ID`),
  KEY `FK4BE75322382D11BC` (`loan_ID`),
  KEY `POSTING_DATE` (`postingDate`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=230996702 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Slave:

```
| Loan  | CREATE TABLE `Loan` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amount` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amountToReturn` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isGivenOut` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `isPaid` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `issueDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `loanPeriod` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `productType` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `realPayDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `givenOutDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `isPaidByBank` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `accountNumberNBKI` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `needManualProcessing` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isReverted` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `showInNBCHReport` bit(1) DEFAULT b'1',
  `stake` decimal(19,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ignoreProlongation` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `stakeAfter21` decimal(19,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `showInEquifaxReport` bit(1) DEFAULT b'1',
  `ignoreNbch` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FK2439106EC0BA18` (`product_ID`),
  KEY `ISPAID_INDEX` (`isPaid`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `ISP_ISGOUT_INDEX` (`isPaid`,`isGivenOut`),
  KEY `ISSUEDATE_INDEX` (`issueDate`),
  KEY `FK243910735827C6` (`discount_id`),
  KEY `idx_Loan_realPayDate` (`realPayDate`),
  KEY `idx_Loan_givenOutDate` (`givenOutDate`),
  KEY `FK243910AAD869E6` (`client_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `_FK243910735827C6` FOREIGN KEY (`discount_id`) REFERENCES `Discount` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2000623399 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=4 

 Posting | CREATE TABLE `Posting` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amount` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postingDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `fromAccount_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `loan_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `toAccount_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sourceType` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FK4BE7532292C5D482` (`fromAccount_ID`),
  KEY `FK4BE75322AE503A13` (`toAccount_ID`),
  KEY `FK4BE75322382D11BC` (`loan_ID`),
  KEY `POSTING_DATE` (`postingDate`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=230996702 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=4
```

If remove table Loan from Query

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                              | key     | key_len | ref                         | rows      | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+-----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | range  | PRIMARY,FK4BE7532292C5D482,FK4BE75322AE503A13,POSTING_DATE | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL                        | 107736559 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | af    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                    | PRIMARY | 8       | smsfinance.p.fromAccount_ID |         1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | at    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                    | PRIMARY | 8       | smsfinance.p.toAccount_ID   |         1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+-----------+-------------+
```

If I add
    create index acc on Account(`acc_type`);

Plan:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                                                 | key                | key_len | ref                       | rows | Extra                                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | af    | range  | PRIMARY,acc                                                                   | acc                | 21      | NULL                      | 4192 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | ref    | PRIMARY,FK4BE7532292C5D482,FK4BE75322AE503A13,FK4BE75322382D11BC,POSTING_DATE | FK4BE7532292C5D482 | 9       | smsfinance.af.ID          |   54 | Using index condition; Using where                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | l     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                       | PRIMARY            | 8       | smsfinance.p.loan_ID      |    1 | NULL                                                   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | at    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,acc                                                                   | PRIMARY            | 8       | smsfinance.p.toAccount_ID |    1 | Using where                                            |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Query execute long time.

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why this might happen.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for `l` and `p`, plus the query in question.  I doubt if compression is relevant.  What version(s) are the mysqls?

Comment: Edit main post.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect compression leads to different statistics, which can lead to different execution plans.

I see no use for the table `Loan` in this query.  Removing it from the query may force the explain plans to be the same.

You have 200M rows in each table?  Another speedup would be to shrink the tables.

- Change `BIGINT` (8 bytes each) to `INT UNSIGNED` (4 bytes, range 0..4 billion) wherever possible.
- Normalize the `_type` columns, replacing with `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (2 bytes, range 0..64K) or other suitable integer type.  Or turn the column into an `ENUM` if there are a finite, small number, of "types".

Does `Account` have `INDEX(acc_type)`?  (Or at least *starting* with acc_type.)

Remove `INNER JOIN Loan AS l ON p.loan_id = l.ID` and replace `l.client_ID AS 'client_ID',` with

```
( SELECT client_ID FROM Loans WHERE ID = p.loan_id ) AS 'client_ID',
```

I think this will force a different query plan, perhaps a good one.

Comment: Sorry, I've made mistake in query.  Now tables Loan exist in query.

Comment: No, Account has index  with acc_type and client_ID' UNIQUE KEY `idx_unique_client_acc_type` (`client_ID`,`acc_type`)'

Comment: I need an index _starting_ with acc_type.

Comment: See my added suggestion for dealing with Loan.

Comment: Good way with Loan, but I don't understand why does mysql change plan? And how i can prevent this change? Because I must change another query.

Comment: You cannot _directly_ prevent the change without put serious downside risk.  Here's another thing that _might_ help:  `ANALYZE TABLE`.